# Forward specific input to different graph operations based on condition vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a computational graph in TensorFlow able to forward different part of the input data to different operations based on a supplementary input vector which specifies which operation to use.

For example, suppose that you have an input tensor **A** whose dimensions are (3, 2, 10, 10). What I want to do is to forward the input data **A**, according to a vector **c**=[1, 0, 1], to specific operations. In particular, the first row **A[0]** should be forwarded to the operation associated to the value 1 in the vector **c**, the second row **A[1]** should be forwarded to the operation associated to the value 0, and so on and so forth.

Suppose that each operation is defined in a function whose parameters should be like the following:

```
def build_op_1(input, param1, param2, param3):
    # returns tensor operation for op_1
    pass

def build_op_2(input, param1, param2, param3, param4):
    # returns tensor operation for op_2
    pass
```

where *input* is the i-th row of **A**. As you can see, I need to retrieve the correct operation for the i-th row of the input and execute it on it. This must be done for all the row contained in **A**.

I have seen that there are operations able to manage the conditional flow in the graph (i.e., *case*, *switch*, etc.) but I think that they are not able to forward specific data to specific operations. Is there a way to achieve this kind of behaviour in TensorFlow?

Thank you in advance,

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the tensorflow map_fn to iterate over the rows, coupled with a tensorflow cond to conditionally run different subgraphs.

Comment: Sorry if I answer late. I have solved my problem exactly using a combination of tf.map_fn and tf.case. Anyway, thank you for your help!